# 404 Error on Activate / Deactivate Plugin

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

I have a standard WP install (3.5.1) and am trying to activate a new plugin (WP Super Cache) however each time I try to activate it, I get my site's 404 error page... which is strange as it's the same page (wp-admin/plugins.php) as the plugin list page I'm activating from, but with a query string. Stranger still is that I cannot deactivate, or activate any of my other plugins?!?

I haven't changed the `.htaccess` file or made any changes to the permalink structure and can't seem to nail down what is going on?

There doesn't seem to be any resource on this anywhere; anyone have any ideas?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try setting the permalink structure to default, then check if still the way it is.

Comment: @01100001 Just tried it and now instead of the 404 I get a 500 (internal server error + 400). Also checked all of the directories to see if there was a conflicting .htaccess and they're clean.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone running into a similar problem, it came down to a plugin conflict; in my case [Capability Manager Enhanced](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/) and Access which is part of the [Toolset](http://wp-types.com/) plugin. Unfortunately no `error_log` of `/var/log/httpd` log files were generated as it was an internal permissions conflict within WordPress.

If you find yourself in this situation, simply FTP / SSH into the server and rename / delete the plugin you don't want from the `/wp-content/plugins/` directory and reload your Admin -> Plugins page.

I hope this helps someone!